# Cocos2d animate CCSprite width/height

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to animate CCSprite width/height in cocos2d ? I'm looking to animate the menu panel width, scaleX/scaleY property animation is not the solution for my case.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is "Yes". You need to ask a better question if you want a different answer. What sort of animation? What are you trying to do? What isn't working? etc...

Comment: I'm trying to make an animation similar to UIKit animations, for example [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [board setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 30)];
    }];

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do as there is very little data.

But you can take a look at [CCMoveTo](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_move_to.html) and [CCScaleTo](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_scale_to.html).

These will move and scale your sprite over a given time.

You can group these together (I think) to run them both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a lot of animations available in cocos2d. you may want to run multiple action on a sprite sequentially or parallel on a node/sprite. For example i have a sprite and i want to scale its size, blink and then fade out to it. Then i would do

```
      CCSPrite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"xyz.png"];
       .....
      CCScaleTo *scale = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scaleX:20 scaleY:30];
      CCBlink *blink = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.3 blinks:2];
      CCFadeTo *fade = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.3 opacity:0];
```

To run all the above actions one after other:

```
      [mySPrite runAction:[CCSequence actions:scale, blink, fade, nil]];
```

To run all the actions at same time:

```
      [mySprite runAction:[CSPawn actions:scale, blink, fade, nil]];
```

There are a lot of action like this you implement inorder to get an animation effect. Read the cocos2d documentaion.